# Can a BroadcastReceiver pass control to a Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Can a BroadcastReceiver pass control to a Activity?

Maybe I am thinking about this in the wrong way but I have a BroadcasterReceiver waiting for a SMS message to come in.  once it comes in I would like it to pass control to a Activity so the Activity can set a alarm and beep.  but the following code will not build inside the BroadcastReceiver

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneFinder.class, AlarmService.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I found the rest of your source code in one of the many other questions you asked about this at the same time, and I will answer it there.  Please do not cross-post so many questions about the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

An explicit Intent like the one you've written takes a Context and the class you want to launch as parameters, not two class names.  The onReceive() method, where you are probably attempting this, passes you a context parameter that you can use to do this.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Launch Activity
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, PhoneFinder.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
}
```

This will launch PhoneFinder when a broadcast is picked up by the receiver.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: it will not build still I get a underdef on startActivity

Comment: I also tryed changing it to:

Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
context.startActivity(startIntent);

but the Alarm never gets called